# DataTables How to Set Width for Spesific Td

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using latest version of [DataTables.](http://www.datatables.net/)

I have a simple problem but i haven't solved it yet. I just want to set a width for spesific td.

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
            ,

        });
    });
</script>

 <style>


     #myid{
  text-align: right;
  background: #b6Cfe5;
  width: 200px;

 }

</style>
```

My td

```
 <td   id=myid "> Bla Bla</td>
 <th   ">Bla Bla</th>
```

I want to set width 200px to myid td. How can i solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Your HTML is wrong syntax wise and id's must be **unique**... Set the width like so: `#myid { width: 200px; }`

Comment: I changed and edited but i failed again.

Comment: This is working: http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/2145/